# Epson xp-305 printer scanner

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, scanner, epson

I've just re-installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 and a few days later gone to install the printer driver for an XP-305 printer/scanner but I have not been able to get the scanner to work.

I've downloaded two packages from the Epson website:

epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.6.35-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb

and

epson-printer-utility_1.0.2-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb

and I also got iscan-bundle-1.0.4.x64.deb.tar.gz, I think also from the Epson website.

Once I'd unpackaged the .tar.gz I tried to follow the README.rst file but I think I may have made a mistake somewhere along the line and, to be fair, I am now pretty lost with it all.

I would hugely appreciate someone's help to get the scanner utility on the printer/scanner to work.

Please help if you can. All the best!

Comment: Installing the .deb packages should be enough.

Comment: Hi @GabrielaGarcia, thanks for the comment. I have installed all of the .deb packages and followed the instructions for this, but it is still not working. I get an error message: **Could not send command to scanner. Check the scanner's status.** I've checked that it is on - I think there is some problem in reaching the scanner on the network. I know the printer is on the CUPS network because I can print, but I think this uses something called SANE and I have no idea how to make sure that is working.

Answer (score 1):

I've struggled with this issue too!

I have to say I can't get a printer driver for the 305 to work on any version of Ubuntu up to the current version.

So I gave up - I know that's not what people want to hear but I did.

I have found a work around though.  The Epson 305 is a network printer with remote access - it has its own email address and it is possible to print to it by sending certain file types to this email address (.doc and .pdf for example).

So my solution is to print to a pdf file and email this to the printer.  Not as elegant perhaps but just as quick.

Scanning works the same but in reverse.  Scan on the Epson and email the result or save as a pdf onto a memory card.

You can find your printer's email address (and change it) by going on the Epson website.